# Cannot connect Mysql-Apache PHP7 Windows10 WITHOUT WAMPP MAMPP EasyPHP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, database-connection

I am a very junior dev working in a small software company.

Since I started 5 daysago  I have database connection problems. Everything started from the setting up of my new working environment.

I have now a PC working on windows 10  and I had to install Apache 2.4 and php7 'manually', without using Wampp, Ampp etc. I did it, many times, comparing each line of my configuration and framework lines to those of my colleagues but I am still not able log in my users, to dysplay use the database, etc. In the browser (any) the error message is "Cannot connect to database".

My company uses Mysql workbench (my boss does not like it) and SQLyog (prefered to manage the databases). So I tried to solve the problem installinf phpMyAdmin. I cheked any parameter, the php.ini is good, every file is well located.

When I try to reach index/php/phpmyadmin (we use our own mvc framework) I geta message error sayong thar msqli extension is missing, with this link :  http://localhost/phpmyadmin/doc/html/faq.html#faqmysql. Please note that I have this in my php.ini :

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
;extension=php_ftp.dll
;extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll

and there is no error in extension_dir = ******/****/
```

Can you help me please?

Cordially

Comment: Why do you need phpmyadmin? Can't you use the suggested tools like: Mysql workbench or SQLyog?

Comment: Hi Roland, I only wanted to try and discover what would happens with phpmyAdmin. Now I think that there is a problem with my php.ini but I do not understand why.

Comment: Hi, idk, could you output `<?php phpinfo();`  and verify that the mysqli extension is loaded?

Comment: I finally found the solution : I needed to unquote ";http://php.net/extension-dir" . Why? I do not know  since I already had unquoted  "extension_dir = "C:/PHP7/ext" and  extension_dir = "ext"  .  I reach localhost/phpmyamdmin. phpmyadmin works very well... That said I  am still not able to connect to my database when I use my controlllers and my views. Error : "Cannot connect to database".

Comment: check if you can somehow get a better error. like network or password...